# Mapping Stored Procedure doesn't return one string

Tags: entity-framework

I am trying to map the following stored procedure in Entity Framework. It clearly should return one string but I cannot get it to do so. When I do a Function Import, it maps to the choice return a collection of scalar string. If I set it to None, it just returns a int. Is it the SP? Is there no support for select stored procedures?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getCurrentConnection]
    @registrationID VARCHAR(100)

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT TOP 1 ConnectionGUID FROM clientconnection WHERE registrationid = @registrationID ORDER BY created desc
END
```

The generated code does:

```
 public virtual ObjectResult<string> SPgetCurrentConnection(string registrationID)
        {
            var registrationIDParameter = registrationID != null ?
                new ObjectParameter("registrationID", registrationID) :
                new ObjectParameter("registrationID", typeof(string));

            return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<string>("SPgetCurrentConnection", registrationIDParameter);
        }
```

I also can't delete the SP from my model and start again. I don't see it on the designer. It only lets me modify and that gives the Prefix SP in front of it

Comment: We are modifying the SP to return the string in an OUTPUT parameter and see if that generates the right code.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by modifying the SP to return an Output parameter.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getCurrentConnection]
    @registrationID VARCHAR(100),   
    @connectionID varchar(100) OUTPUT

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT @connectionID = (SELECT TOP 1 ConnectionGUID FROM clientconnection WHERE registrationid = @registrationID ORDER BY created DESC)
END
```

Then writing the function in code:

```
public string GetCurrentConnection(string accountId)
        {

            using (savitasEntities2 db = new savitasEntities2())
            {
                string cid = String.Empty;
                ObjectParameter connectionId = new ObjectParameter("connectionID", typeof(string));
                db.GetCurrentConnection(accountId, connectionId);
                return connectionId.Value.ToString();
            }
        }
```